# A macro that takes in a variable that is a number, interprets it as a string, check if it has a plus sign, removes it, then stores it to the variable

Tags: math-mode, macros, strings, variable, renewcommand

I want to create a macro `\foo` that takes in a `\newcommand` variable that is a number, e.g., `\bar` where it's defined as

```
\newcommand{\bar}{<number>}
```

and interprets it as a string, then checks if it has a plus sign (`+`), and removes it if so or do nothing otherwise, then store the string back into the variable `\bar` through a `\renewcommand`(?) redefinition.

The desired result would be something as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,DIV=12]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\bari}{}
\newcommand{\barii}{}
\newcommand{\bariii}{}
\newcommand{\testbar}{\[\text{bar}_{\text{i}} = \bari,\, \text{bar}_{\text{ii}} = \barii,\, \text{bar}_{\text{iii}} = \bariii. \]}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{...}

\begin{document}
\noindent\textbf{Before:}
\renewcommand{\bari}{-2.5}
\renewcommand{\barii}{+7}
\renewcommand{\bariii}{\frac{4}{3}}
\testbar
\textbf{After:}
\foo{\bari}
\foo{\barii}
\foo{\bariii}
\testbar
\end{document}
```

### *How can I define such a macro?*

Comment: Would you be interested in a LuaLaTeX-based solution? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Yes, that would be nice since I mainly use LuaLaTeX nowadays. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This works reasonably well:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\ahmed#1{\ahmedA#1\relax+\ahmedA #1}
\long\def\ahmedA#1+#2\ahmedA{\ifx\@nnil#1\@nnil \expandafter\@gobble \fi}
\makeatother

\ahmed{123}\ \ahmed{+123}\ \ahmed{+++}\ \ahmed{}
```

[image: output]

With slight modifications we can make it store the result in a macro instead.

```
\long\def\ahmed#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter
    {\romannumeral \ahmedA#2\relax+\ahmedA #2}}
\long\def\ahmedA#1+#2\ahmedA{\ifx\@nnil#1\@nnil \expandafter\@firstoftwo \fi \z@}
```

Comment: I tried using the slightly modified version and it works if I use `\ahmed{<macro>}{<number>}` but not if I use `\ahmed{<macro>}{<another macro>}`. Is it possible to have a syntax that allows a macro input as the second argument that will be interpreted as a string? Thank you.